# Mail group managers similar to Plesk

Tags: drupal, email, linux, mailing-list, plesk

I'm relocating my client's pages to a new server. Their old system was running Plesk and had some email groups and a few mail forwards defined. The new server has no Plesk and I'd really rather not install it just for the email groups either, so I'm looking for a new alternative for creating and managing the lists.

Their main site is going to run on Drupal 6.x, so a module for that would be the preferred choice. I tried searching for one myself, but to no avail.

Anything else that gets the job done will do as well, as long as the client who is not very tech-savvy can modify and add lists herself. The server is a Debian 5, root access is available.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally ended up with was [Sympa](http://www.sympa.org/). It's a pain to set up the www interface, but I finally got it working with [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/). A Drupal module would have been nice but this solution is totally acceptable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://drupal.org/project/mailchimp

It integrates [mailchimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) with drupal, so you will need to sign up for that.

Please note: I haven't actually tried it, I just found it on drupal.org and it looked like it would do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I signed up for mailchimp but it seems to be more of a campaign email tool. What I'm looking for is mail groups and mail forwarding.

Comment: Have you tried using the plugin with mailchimp? According to the plugin features page (I haven't actually used the plugin, I'm just looking at the plugin's page at drupal.org), you can assign a mailchimp list to a role in drupal.

Comment: The lists in Plesk allow defining lists like mylist@mydomain.com so that all emails sent to that address are forwarded to a list of people. I couldn't find any functionality like that in Mailchimp.